# Getting Error 401--Unauthorized in Postman when using post method to make a to call external API

Tags: proxy, postman, unauthorized

I am trying to get the response back from API using Postman native app in windows 10.
I am in my company system which uses proxy, so i need to pass proxy credentials for every request which i send from my system.
As per postman documentation, i set proxy settings but still getting 401: Unauthorized error.

[Postman Proxy Settings](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/proxy)

Other suggestion was to use Basic Authentication while sending a request. It doesn't help either:

[Baisc Auth settings for Proxy in postman](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/1330851/19229048/2d913782-8ee8-11e6-8b1b-56cf5c6365c7.gif)

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the things in native app but it's not working.
The workaround is to use Chrome extension for Postman.
Please refer the steps below:

> 1.> Search for Postman Interceptor chrome extension
>
> 2.> Install the extension
>
> 3.> Launch postman extension
>
> 4.> Login using your google account Or register an account in postman.
>
> 5.> When you try to login, pop appear in which proxy userid and password needs to be entered.
>
> 6.> Once proxy settings has been updated, send the request. You should receive expected response back.

Happy coding :)